# Keras: printing out the predicted class label

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I'm testing a CNN model based on the cifar10 keras dataset. So, basically

```
prediction = mymodel.predict(x)
print(prediction)
```

prints out the prediction itself:

```
[[3.3675440e-04 5.7650192e-07 2.5850117e-02 5.4446888e-01 7.0444457e-02
  1.7459875e-01 3.5874096e-03 1.8062484e-01 1.2066155e-06 8.6996079e-05]]
```

What's the correct syntax, given the cifar10 class labels

```
classes = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
```

to print the **predicted label** instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it should be something like that:

```
prediction = mymodel.predict(x)
# return position of max:
max_position = np.argmax(prediction)  
prediction_label = classes[max_position]
print(prediction_label)
```

Comment: Thanks. So the resulting array is interpreted as the the probability of being present in the image per class?

Comment: The result array contain the outputs of your last NN layer (before the output layer) . The item which have the maximum value is the item predict by your model. Mathematically it's not the % of probability but it's quiet close (if your model is well trained)